# gearvrf - How to position camera position to be inside my 3d model

Tags: android, 3d, gear-vr

So I have a 3ds model of an apartment. So I managed to insert the apartment in the app

```
    GVRScene scene = gvrContext.getMainScene();

    GVRSceneObject apartment = null;
    try {
        apartment = gvrContext.loadModel("room.3ds");
    } catch ...
```

I get that, yay it's working

[image]

Then now what I am trying to achieve is to be INSIDE that apartment. So what I have done is trying to move the apartment in 3d space.

```
 apartment.getTransform().setPosition(0f,0f,-500f);
```

Now for sure I did not get into the apartment, but I also had something between me and the apartment (see the curvy black thing)
[image]

So question is, how to be INSIDE that apartment?

Bonus question: what are the values that i should be using for x,y and z ? like what range ?

Comment: The problem is mostly on how you construct your camera with near and far distance. You just have to find a coordinate that falls inside the model.

Comment: Do I move the camera using             `scene.getMainCameraRig().getTransform().setPosition(x,y,z);` ? because when i did that i had the problem of the second photo, it was like there was some sort of a round wall between the camera and the object.

Comment: I decided to move to Unity3d. Using gearVRf is hell on earth to position and move objects

Answer (score 0):

Hi Nani sorry you are having problems.

It looks to me by translating the room model -500f in the z direction, it moved farther away from you and now clips through the camera's far plane (and the round black wall).

If so, this is a problem you will also encounter in Unity. In all cases, either move it closer to you (for example, +500f in the z direction) and see what happens, or adjust the camera's far distance, thus pushing back the far plane.

And if you haven't already, please post at https://github.com/Samsung/GearVRf/issues
There are a lot more Samsung developers working on GearVRf who can help you there